# Twitter Friend list api is giving Cross-Origin Request Blocked error

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In Mozilla i am getting error as:Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource
(Reason: CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' missing).

and in chrome I am getting error as :

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   https://api.twitter.com/1.1/friends/list.json Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource.  The response had HTTP status code 400.

I tried google it but I dint get proper answer. any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is working as intended. You're not supposed to call the API directly from a web browser.

This is called [CORS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing).